# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, list

There is an error,when I try to split

```
l =[u'this is friday', u'holiday begin']
split_l =l.split()
print(split_l)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\spotify_track2.py", line 19, in <module>
    split_l =l.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So I don't have idea to deal with this kind of error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `split()`?

Comment: Well obviously the best way to "deal with this kind of error" is to avoid trying to call methods that dont exist xD. Now what are you trying to do exactly ? What did you expect `list.split` to return ?

Comment: does it any way to get the print like this? a =['this', 'is', friday', 'holiday',' begin'] @Shashank

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is what I expected to return a =['this', 'is', friday', 'holiday',' begin']

Comment: So you already got the answer. Just out of curiousity: what would you expect `[1, 2, 3].split()` to return then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, do not name your variable as `list`

Secondly `list` does not have the function `split` It is `str` which has it.

Check the documentation for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> Return a list of the words in the **string**, using sep as the delimiter string

(emphasis mine)

So you need to do

```
l =[u'this is friday', u'holiday begin']
split_list =[i.split() for i in l]
print(split_list)
```

Which would print

```
[[u'this', u'is', u'friday'], [u'holiday', u'begin']]
```

**Post Comment edit**

To get what you expected you can try

```
>>> l =[u'this is friday', u'holiday begin']
>>> " ".join(l).split(" ")
[u'this', u'is', u'friday', u'holiday', u'begin']
```

or as mentioned below

```
>>> [j for i in split_list for j in i]
[u'this', u'is', u'friday', u'holiday', u'begin']
```

Comment: or `[j  for i in split_list for j in i]`

Comment: @xnx why j for i need to repeat twice?

Comment: Bhargav Rao's answer should be all you need. The repeat `for` is to flatten the list from `[[u'this', u'is', u'friday'], [u'holiday', u'begin']]` to `[u'this', u'is', u'friday', u'holiday', u'begin']`.

Comment: @user3849475 That is called flattening of a list, just like what xnx has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

as split() is a string function, we simply need to convert the list object into string and then apply split as follows:

```
`>>`I =[u'this is friday', u'holiday begin']
`>>`I=str(I)
`>>`split_I =I.split()
`>>`print(split_I)
```